# adding active class to parent list when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

adding active class to parent list when link is clicked/active , am trying to inject that using `JavaScript` as follow:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        //injecting active status to the navigation bar lists
        var element = document.getElementById("navbar-ul");
        var links   = element.getElementsByTagName("a");

        for(var i = 0; i < links.length ; i++) {
            links[i].onclick(function () {
                links[i].parent().addClass('active');
            });
        }
    }
);
```

but am getting the following error:

`TypeError: links[i].onclick is not a function`

how I supposed to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simply with jQuery:

```
$("#navbar-ul a").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");       
});
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/98ndkfpg/1/)

I'm guessing you're trying to add an active state to the link thats being clicked on and remove the others? If so you can use `.siblings()` to find the other links and remove their class:

```
$("#navbar-ul a").click(function(){
   $(this).closest("li").addClass("active").siblings("li").removeClass("active");   

});
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/98ndkfpg/)

Answer (score 3):

A more verbose JQuery way to approach this

```
$('#navbar-ul a').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: its better for sure (Y)

Comment: `.bind` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You would be better of with adding a class to the  tags who needs an eventListener. (with jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#navbar-ul a").on("click", function() {
        var active = document.querySelector('#navbar-ul .active');
        if(active){
            $("#navbar-ul a").removeClass('active');
        }
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

);